# File Handling. How to save the progress in a file?

Tags: export, import, files-and-directories

Assuming I already have the file created.

I have a programme that,returns an output, in our case number.
I want Mathematica to save this number in a file, together with results saved from previous calculations.

After having checked Mathematica commands, I found that I could do something like:

```
file = OpenWrite["test.dat"];
Write[file, new];
Close[file];
```

However, this doesn't work, because it overwrites the information that is already in the file. Working with this limitation, I tried a different approach:

```
results=Import["test.dat", "Table"];
AppendTo[results,newresult];
file = OpenWrite["test.dat"];
Write[file,results];
Close[file];
```

This new approach still doesn't work since when I initialize the file test.dat with

```
Export["test.dat", Range[1, 10]]
```

and then import the list, I do not get the same list, but

```
{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}}
```

I get the same unwanted list, even if I add the "Table" option to Export, or Import...

How do I efficiently save the progress of my programme in the file test.dat?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See `Put` and `PutAppend`

Comment: Related: "[The best way to construct a function with memory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5291299/590388)."

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer The PutAppend also seems to overwrite the info, and doesn't solve the import data problem

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov could you explain a bit the code of your link, under the section of File-backed In-memory Approach. It's a bit difficult for me to understand...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea, try this: `(# >>> "test.dat") & /@ {1, 2, 3}` followed by `ReadList["test.dat"]`. For me, this returns `{1,2,3}`. If you now want to add some new numbers, say `(# >>> "test.dat") & /@ {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}`, you will find that `ReadList["test.dat"]` gives you `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`. If you only need to save numbers/lists, and not expressions, then this is the simplest way I can think of.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, Thanks for your help.There's still a little problem though...

I saved {1,2,3,4}, then I do (# >>> "test.dat") & /@{1,2,3}, I get {1, 2, 3, 41, 2, 3} when using ReadList, instead of {1, 2, 3, 4,1, 2, 3}

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea, I can't reproduce that. Did you save it both times with `>>>`? Try starting from a new file name.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer You're right. The first time, I used Export instead of >>>. I get it now. Many thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simply saving numbers or lists to file, I personally prefer to use `Put`/`>>`  and `PutAppend`/`>>>` to store data, and `ReadList` to retrieve it. For instance:

```
(# >>> "file.dat") & /@ {1,2,3};
ReadList["file.dat"]
(* {1,2,3} *)
(# >>> "file.dat") & /@ {1,2,3,4,5};
ReadList["file.dat"]
(* {1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5} *)
```

You could obviously also store the lists each time and then `Join` them if you want:

```
{1, 2, 3} >>> "file.dat";
{4, 5, 6, 7} >>> "file.dat";
Join @@ ReadList["file.dat"]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Open the file with [`OpenAppend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenWrite.html) not `OpenWrite`. Any Writes will then append to the file not overwrite.

Comment: this is especially useful in combination with `ExportString` for text like formats where you can append line by line, e.g. CSV.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Ymareth